# How to print remainder in assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to get the remainder of 2013/10 and add 1 to it

this is what I did so far, however, I'm only getting the quotient even though I've added 1 to `edx` (which is the remainder)  and I've also moved `A` to `eax` so I can print it using `call writedec`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? how can I get the remainder and add 1 to it? I am using MASM assembler

```
.data
    N dword 2013
    A dword 0
    str1 byte " A is =",0

.code
     main proc
     lea edx, str1
     call writestring
     mov edx, 0
     mov eax, N
     mov ebx, 10
     div ebx
     Add edx, 1
     add A, edx
     mov eax, A
     call writedec
     call crlf
```

Comment: You are adding the remainder to A which isn't initialized properly (i.e. contains random data)

Comment: I've tried using mov A, edx as well and it didn't work also

Comment: What assembler are you using? And what output are you actually getting?

Comment: Which machine are you programming for? Which assembler?

Comment: I'm using massam. I'm getting 201 which is 2013/10 without the remainder

Comment: What happens if you replace `mov eax, A` with `mov eax, edx`? (Note: I'm not sure why the `mov eax, A` you have isn't working after fixing the other problem mentioned; it's acting like the `mov eax, A` instruction isn't there). You still need to fix the problem of `A` being uninitialized.

Comment: I changed A ? to A 0 and I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the exact code that is written in the question? And that you didn't have any compilation errors that would result in an older version of the executable being used? I tried the code in the question (I used NASM so I replaced the `writestring` and `writedec` functions with my own), and got the expected output of 4 (`(2013 % 10) + 1`).

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but it didn't work with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this two line

```
 add A, edx
 mov eax, A
```

with this line :

```
mov eax,edx
```

Comment: Same thing. Technically there is no difference between these two. In fact, I want to add the remainder value to A

Comment: after `mov eax,edx` line , you can move you value to A : `mov A,eax` .